# Languages that compile into sh

Tags: posix, sh

Which languages(think csh, ksh, bash, zsh..) compile into posix compatible sh?

Please include a brief description of the language.

I'm specifically looking for any languages that might remove (hide) the standard posix pitfalls, while still having the flexibility of transportation like posix.

Comment: Closers please leave comments.  (If the answer is none, then leave that as an answer instead of requesting to close)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only tool I know that compiles "input" into POSIX `sh` is [`shar`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar), which makes a "shell archive" out of the input files. It's like `tar(1)`, except it `uuencode(1)`s the output for transmission over usenet or email.

No one has used it in years because the archives are *executable files*; simply unpacking a file requires giving someone else execution permission on your machine, which is patently stupid.